# Pasch's axiom, intermediate value theorem and Jordan curve theorem

Tags: euclidean-geometry, axioms, axiomatic-geometry

All of these three conclusions seem "obvious" to laypeople, and they appear to be somehow connected. I am wondering whether Pasch's axiom can be viewed as a corollary of intermediate value theorem (IVT) and/or Jordan curve theorem (JCT) with appropriate settings. However, I have failed to deduce Pasch's axiom from IVT and/or JCT without further recourse to even less obvious "axioms", which makes me speculate that Pasch's axiom is indeed much more "fundamenetal" than IVT and/or JCT.

Comment: IVT and JCT, as geometric statements, make sense in plane *coordinate* geometry. In that setting, Pasch's axiom should just be provable by getting your hands dirty. Pasch's axiom is worth thinking about in a more synthetic setting, where I struggle to see how you'd even state the other two results.

Comment: In a synthetic setting, IVT may be stated as follows: if two points are on opposite sides of a given straight line, then any plane curve connecting the aforementioned two points must intersect the given line.

Comment: But what is a curve? Maybe we can define it as a piecewise linear curve, line segments being something we can work with?

Comment: A curve may be defined as a continuous bijective mapping of a line.

Comment: That just means we have to worry about continuity, which is not trivial either. But in fact I have an answer where the piecewise-linear version of the IVT is all we need to deduce Pasch's axiom.

Comment: I think continuity may be defined via the notion of distance, which in turn may be axiomatized by ruler postulate and triangle inequality. What about JCT?

Comment: In this paper, the authors mention a  proof of JCT from a subset of Hilbert's axioms  (without continuity assumptions): https://www.pure.ed.ac.uk/ws/portalfiles/portal/19004266/Scott_and_Fleuriot_2010_Towards_a_synthetic_proof.pdf

Comment: They also details the proof of JCT in the special case of a polygon reduced to a single triangle.

Answer (score 1):

For the IVT, as stated in the comments:

Suppose line $\ell$ intersects side $AB$ of $\triangle ABC$. (In other words, line $\ell$ intersects line $AB$ at a point $X$ such that $X$ is between $A$ and $B$.)

Then $A$ and $B$ are on different sides of $\ell$. (This is commonly *defined* exactly as above: the intersection point of $AB$ with $\ell$ lies between $A$ and $B$.)

By the IVT, the curve that goes from $A$ to $B$ by following segment $AC$ then segment $CB$ must also intersect $\ell$, which is exactly Pasch's axiom.

Comment: Of course it depends on the way in which IVT is "rendered" into synthetic geometry. Personally, I think IVT is related to completeness, but in a synthetic setting, it appears that completeness of line does not imply my "rephrasing" of IVT  without Pasch's axiom.